# Weak absolute continuity of measures

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show that if we have a function $f \in L^p$ sucht that $||f||_p =1$.

Define a new measure $\mu$ by

$$\mu(A):=\int_A |f(x)|^p dm(x).$$

Then $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \delta>0$ such that the following implication holds:

$$m(A)< \delta \Rightarrow \mu(A) < \epsilon.$$

I read a few things in wikipedia and noticed that this is somehow related to the absolute continuity of measures, but I don't know anything about this. Maybe, you can give me a hint how to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Considering $|f|^p$ instead of $f$, we can assume that $p=1$ and $f$ is non-negative.
2. For each simple function $s:=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i\chi_{B_i}$, where $a_i$ are non-negative real numbers and $B_i$ disjoint measurable sets, and each measurable set $A$,
   $$\mu(A)=\int_A|f-s+s|\mathrm m(x)\leqslant \int_A|f-s|\mathrm dm(x)+\int_As(x)\mathrm dm(x)\\\leqslant\lVert f-s\rVert_1+\left(\sum_{i=1}^Na_i\right)m(A)\tag{*}.$$
3. We can conclude by $(*)$ by a $2\varepsilon$-argument: take $s$ such that $\lVert f-s\rVert_1\lt \varepsilon$; then define $\delta:=\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\sum_{i=1}^Na_i}$.

Comment: Is it necessary to assume that the measure is $\sigma$-finite? I think it probably is.

Comment: @Frank Where would $\sigma$-finiteness play a role? In any case, we can reduce the measure space to $\{f\neq 0\}$ which is a countable union of sets of finite measure.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I have a question. In the first line, you meant considering f instead of $|f|^p$, right? and according to the construction of $s$, do we assume that all $B_i \subset A$ ? And do you further take the ||.||_1-norm as an integral over the whole measure space or just $A$ (I would guess, just $A$)?

Comment: I take the $L^1$ norm on the whole space. The $B_i's$ are not necessarily contained in $A$. For the first point, define $g:=|f|^p$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo In that case I don't see, how you got this $m(A)$ in the expression (*) ? $\sum_{i=1}^Na_i m(B_i)$ is what I would have there and if we would have assumed $B_i \subset A$, it would be clear, but since we don't, I don't see where this $m(A)$ comes from?

Comment: I've edited, is it clearer?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo indeed, it is, that was basically why i was wondering over which set you had taken the norm. thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome.